# How to fix this AC switching circuit?

Tags: opto-isolator, switching, triac

I am trying to replicate a small circuit of an optocoupler and a triac, see this document for details (second page / "EL Channels"):
http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/EL/SparkFun_EL_Sequencer_v23.pdf

A picture of the circuit:
[image: circuit]

The problem is that I can switch AC out on by applying 5V on the input wire, but it does not switch off when I disconnect the 5V again.

Comment: Looks to me like the circuit you've built doesn't match the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. What you want.*

[image]

*Figure 2. What you've wired.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPqCZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. What you've done and what you meant to do.*

[image]

*Figure 4. The fix.*

Comment: I can see it now, after flipping your images upside down. I can see that compared to your schematic, the G and T1 pins on the triac are reversed, so I would need to solder that element upside down, or go over-under, right?

Comment: No, if your triac is right side upwards then the terminals are as I have marked in yellow - according to the datasheet I found for the Z0103MN. As far as I can see you need to desolder the XX wire and connect it to G as shown in green.